# wro4j wildcards don't work for classpath?

Tags: css, maven, wro4j

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
    <group name="index">
        <css>classpath:gss/**</css>
    </group>
</groups>
```

results in

```
[INFO] wroManagerFactory class: ro.isdc.wro.extensions.manager.standalone.GoogleStandaloneManagerFactory
0    WARN DefaultWildcardStreamLocator - No resource found for wildcard: **
4    WARN DefaultWildcardStreamLocator - No resource found for wildcard: **
15   WARN DefaultWildcardStreamLocator - No resource found for wildcard: **
```

But

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
    <group name="index">
        <css>classpath:gss/compass/screen.gss</css>
    </group>
</groups>
```

Results in

```
[INFO] file size: index.css -> 1001 bytes
```

Is there something simple i'm missing about the wildcard matching ? Wro4j 1.6.2

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. Follow the progress on the page where the [issue was reported](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/issues/detail?id=680&start=100).

Comment: I still have the problem (november 2016), I'm not sure : is it fixed or not ?  I use version 1.8.0.